# Disable end of line normalization via .gitattributes file

Tags: git, normalization, line-endings, eol, gitattributes

How can I disable end of line normalization (line terminator) via .gitattributes file? Or more usefully, disable it for certain paths and/or files. Also I want Git to show diff's/merge's as per usual for text files.

Since sometimes you need to normalize line endings for text files depending on the OS (i.e. using `* text=auto` in the `.gitattributes` file), how can exclusions be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Given all text files are normalized in .gitattributes file, we can add exclusions using the `!eol` option:

```
# Auto detect text files and perform EOL normalization according to OS
* text=auto 

#Exclude certain file types from EOL normalization
*.csv !eol

#Exclude certain paths from EOL normalization
**/TestFilesPath/** !eol
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to specify the actual EOL you want in a given case, or if the files are not text, specify `-text`?

Comment: @bk2204 Nearly all the examples online are specifying a specific EOL. For my scenario I want to specifically tell Git to leave the text file alone and not normalize it under any OS. The scenario is producing a text file for a bank for payment instructions, I always want a predictable file to base the tests on.